# Create a toggle button to change theme in Python Shiny

Tags: python, py-shiny

I am building a web app using Python Shiny, I am trying to create a toggle switch such that one can change the app theme by turning it on and off. The challenge I am facing is that the theme changes when you click on it once, with subsequent clicks it just remains constant and refuses to change. I don't know if it has something to do with my code. Here is my code below

```
import shinyswatch
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, render, ui, reactive
import pandas as pd

sales = pd.read_csv("data/sales_data.csv")
warehouse_option = sales["warehouse"].unique().tolist()
product_option = sales["product_line"].unique().tolist()


app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.page_navbar(
        ui.nav(
            "Sales Dashboard",
            ui.output_ui("theme"),
            ui.layout_sidebar(
                ui.panel_sidebar(
                    ui.input_switch("theme_toggle", "Change Theme"),
                    ui.input_selectize("warehouse", "Select Warehouse", warehouse_option),
                    ui.input_selectize("product", "Select Product Line", product_option)
                ),
                ui.panel_main(

                )
            )
        ),
        ui.nav(
            "Model Prediction"
        )
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):

    @output
    @render.ui
    def theme():
        x = input.theme_toggle()
    
        if x == True:
            return shinyswatch.theme.vapor()
        else:
            return shinyswatch.theme.lux()

        
app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Here are images showing the theme changing, but the switch only changes the theme once and that's all.
[Light Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugkE.png) and
[Dark Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCKZT.png)

Comment: I think it's a limitation in shiny currently. I made an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/py-shiny/issues/552

Comment: @NealRichardson Thanks, I have been cracking my brain trying to solve it not knowing it was a bug on shiny